# Is there any way to filter a multi-indexed pandas DataFrame using a dict?

Tags: python, pandas

Please consider the following DataFrame:

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels =  [[1, 2, 3], ['red', 'green', 'blue'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], 
    codes = [[1,0,1,0], [0,1,1,2], [1,0,0,1]],
    names = ["Key1", "Key2", "Key3"])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}, index = mi)
```

... which looks like this:
[image]

Now I know how to filter this by values of the index levels, eg:

```
df[
    df.index.get_level_values("Key1").isin([1]) &
    df.index.get_level_values("Key2").isin(["green"]) 
]
```

I'm trying to write a function which makes this operation less verbose, so I'd like to pass in a dict like: `{"Key1":1, "Key2":"green"}` to do the same thing.

The solution shouldn't hardcode the number of levels we are filtering on, so that later, I might want to only filter by one of the conditions, and would pass in `{"Key1":1}` or ``{"Key2":"green"}`.

I don't know the syntax for constructing the predicate inside the `df[ ... ]` on-the-fly from a `dict`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the MultiIndex [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_frame.html), then slice the columns with dictionary keys and check if [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) are equal within a row to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d = {"Key1":1, "Key2":"green"}

out = df[df.index.to_frame()[list(d)].eq(d).all(axis=1)]
```

Alternatively, using [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) and your original approach:

```
out = df[np.logical_and.reduce([df.index.get_level_values(k)==v
                                for k,v in d.items()])]
```

Output:

```
                 values
Key1 Key2  Key3        
1    green a          2
```

Intermediates:

```
# df.index.to_frame()[list(d)]
                 Key1   Key2
Key1 Key2  Key3             
2    red   b        2    red
1    green a        1  green
2    green a        2  green
1    blue  b        1   blue

# df.index.to_frame()[list(d)].eq(d)
                  Key1   Key2
Key1 Key2  Key3              
2    red   b     False  False
1    green a      True   True
2    green a     False   True
1    blue  b      True  False

# df.index.to_frame()[list(d)].eq(d).all(axis=1)
Key1  Key2   Key3
2     red    b       False
1     green  a        True
2     green  a       False
1     blue   b       False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I will need to break that down to digest it, but thank you for the pointer.

Comment: @butterflyknife I added the intermediates for clarity ;)

Comment: Thanks. That was amazingly fast, btw. I am in awe! Upvoted for now, will accept when the timeout is over.

Comment: @butterflyknife you're welcome, I added another approach with [tag:numpy]

Answer (score 3):

One option is with [pyjanitor's select](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select) function :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.select(rows={"Key1":1, "Key2":"green"})
                 values
Key1 Key2  Key3        
1    green a          2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) :

```
d = {"Key1": 1, "Key2": "green"}

out = df.query(" and ".join(map(lambda k: f"{k} == {repr(d[k])}", d)))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                 values
Key1 Key2  Key3        
1    green a          2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a multi-indexed Pandas DataFrame using a dictionary of filter criteria. The keys of the dictionary should correspond to the level names of the multi-index, and the values should specify the values you want to filter on for each level. Here's how you can do it with your example DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the multi-index DataFrame
mi = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels=[[1, 2, 3], ['red', 'green', 'blue'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
    codes=[[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 0, 1]],
    names=["Key1", "Key2", "Key3"])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}, index=mi)

# Define the filter criteria as a dictionary
filter_dict = {
    "Key1": [2, 3],    # Filter for Key1 values 2 and 3
    "Key2": "green",   # Filter for Key2 value 'green'
    "Key3": "a"        # Filter for Key3 value 'a'
}

# Apply the filter using boolean indexing
filtered_df = df[df.index.get_level_values('Key1').isin(filter_dict['Key1']) &
                  (df.index.get_level_values('Key2') == filter_dict['Key2']) &
                  (df.index.get_level_values('Key3') == filter_dict['Key3'])]

print(filtered_df)
```

In this example, filter_dict contains the filter criteria for each level of the multi-index. We use boolean indexing to filter the DataFrame based on the criteria specified in the dictionary. The isin() function is used to check if values in "Key1" are in the list [2, 3], and we compare the values of "Key2" and "Key3" directly for equality.

The resulting filtered_df will contain only the rows that match the filter criteria specified in the dictionary.

Comment: It looks like this answer was AI-generated, it doesn't address the question. OP already knows how to do that and was asking how to use a dictionary as input…